# How to keep JSON keys as strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When running something such as the following:

https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3x4k9njds

The JSON keys will automatically change from strings to identifier names. I am writing to a Firebase Realtime Database, and Firebase will recognize the JSON as being invalid (since JSON keys need to have double quotes). How can I keep JSON keys in double-quotes (most JavaScript compilers will remove them)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console log don't show double quotes, because there's difference between JSON and JavaScript objects.

If you need to convert JavaScript Objects to JSON, you can use

```
JSON.stringify(newData)
```

Comment: Yes I am aware. I think the Invalid JSON error must have been for something else because the issue resolved after a while, despite me still using a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
console.log(JSON.stringify({
  "msg": "hello world",
  "msg2": "testing123"
}));
```

Comment: Firebase Realtime Database requires input as a JSON object. In my program, I will get the permission denied response. While trying the same thing in the Rules Sandbox, I get the error "Invalid JSON". I believe the JSON is invalid simply because JavaScript automatically changes the keys and messes up the syntax. https://ibb.co/ydD6FFc